# Can you renew your passport while traveling abroad?

Tags: passports, argentina

You're a digital nomad, staying in countries 10,000km away from your home country. Your only residency is in Argentina.

Your passport is expiring soon.

Do you have to fly back to Argentina to renew your passport?

Can you go to an Argentina consulate to renew your passport?

Comment: Have you tried asking the nearest Argentinian consulate?

Comment: littleadv isn't being snarky here. The expected behavior on this Stack is that those asking questions will thoroughly search for an answer before asking. You can read the [Help file](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned in which country you would want to apply, and clarified how soon is ‘soon’

Comment: @Traveller is right. Consulates extremely rarely (never?) have the power and equipment to issue passports, they can do the request / verifying part and then ask the home country to print and send the passport. That takes time.

Comment: This is tangential to your question, but it might be safest to go back to Argentina to renew. There's a gentleman in a Japan expat group I belong to that has been waiting over 7 months for his UK passport renewal to be completed. I don't know how Argentina is on these things, but what happens if the renewal takes longer than you're allowed to stay in whatever country you're currently in? And do you need to keep your passport on you in the country you're in?

Comment: Should this be on [Expats.SE]?

Comment: My experience travelling has been that a company will not admit you if your passport may possibly expire within the maximum length of a visitor's VISA. For Canadians travelling to the USA, that means your passport cannot expire within the next 6 months. Assuming this is common practice everywhere, how did this sitation come to be?

Comment: @BrydonGibson That's not the practice for all countries, and in general it may have been missed by the border officials. Some countries also offer visa extensions or visa type changes.

Comment: @gerrit Based on all the other passport renewal questions when not in their home country IMHO this question is OK for here

Comment: Are you an Argentine citizen?  It's not entirely clear from the question.

Answer (score 9):

> Do you have to fly back to Argentina to renew your passport?

No

> Can you go to an Argentina consulate to renew your passport?

https://eungr.cancilleria.gob.ar/en/content/aranceles-de-tramitaciones-m%C3%A1s-frecuentes

> Expedición o renovación de pasaporte (Pasaporte nuevo) 80 + 85*

The answer seems to be yes. However, in countries where there is an embassy and consulates definitely contact them first because it's possible consular services will only be provided by the consulate and not the embassy, strange as that sounds.

> Your passport is expiring soon.

That's a problem, passport books are extremely secure documents and they are not printed by the embassy. They can issue a temporary one to return to Argentina but that can't be used to travel on. An ordinary passport booklet could take *months* for the embassy to ask the home office, get the home office to print it and get it to them. You need to call the embassy ASAP.

Comment: The last part is actually not the case for some consulates, assuming you have an appointment (which can take days to months to get), some will receive and stock blank passport books from the supplier (likely not more than what's needed for the day, and not if the data page is in polycarbonate) and print the data page on the spot at your appointment. Experienced first hand at Paris Italian consulate

Comment: You got a passport book valid for 5-10 year at a consulate?

Comment: For Indian passport, you can renew on consulate. Will get it in 1-2 weeks (I have done that). For emergencies, or passport lost scenario, they will only give a document to return to India and then passport has to be taken from India.

Comment: @chx Yes, I applied and was issued, after ~15min of waiting, a regular, 10 year validity, passport book, I doubt that this is widespread due to the security implications of stocking blank passport books/doing on the spot chip programming, but this is how the consulate general of Italy works here, and, due to the fact that you supply all the paperwork at the appoitment and not before, I am sure they indeed print it and program it on the spot.

Comment: "definitely contact them first" - or just check the website for the embassy/consulate. In my limited experience (not specific to Argentina), these tend to explain in detail which services are available where, and the process for whatever you want to do.

Comment: It's not strange at all. An Embassy (Ambassador) represents their goverment in the host country. A Consulate deals (among other things) with citizen affairs. Many, but not all, Embassies have a Consulate Department inside it that issues passports, visas etc.

Comment: @chx: I also did. The Brazilian consulate in Copenhagen  issues 10-year biometric passports on the spot (well, after 1 hour of waiting). This was the case in multiple renewals of mine and I know for a fact that the consulates in some other countries do that as well.

Comment: "That's a problem, passport books are extremely secure documents and they are not printed by the embassy. " There are special machines that can print a passport on the spot and many consulates do have them. The real problem is that before a passport is issued the authorities must verify that the person is not running away from legal actions, justice or obligations towards eventual spouses and children. Once, such controls were quite slow, today everything is checked online.

Comment: -1: this answer is wrong, or at least does not explain the situation properly. The service of passport renewal at Argentinean consulates is for expats. The only way to do it in OP's situation would be to lie and declare officially at the consulate that one is a resident of the foreign country.

Answer (score 3):

Both posted answers are wrong, at least concerning Argentinean passports. While it is true that you can renew your passport at an Argentinean consulate, that's a service for Argentinean citizens residing in said consulate's jurisdiction, not for tourists. This is clearly explained in the [Argentinean government's website](https://www.argentina.gob.ar/tramitar-el-pasaporte-argentino-en-el-exterior).

Argentinean citizens have their national id card (DNI, "documento nacional de identidad") and said card states the person's address (which in particular implies the electoral district, and this is significant because voting in elections is mandatory in Argentina). To be able to renew the passport at the consulate one needs to officially change this address to an address in the foreign country (and consequently have their DNI renewed). This might be doable if one is willing to deceive the consulate officials, as no proof of residency is usually required. One would have to have the DNI re-issued again on return to Argentina. If my experience with Argentinean consulates is anything to go by, all this would take a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @chx is correct. You can renew your passport at the consulate. But there is a difference between theory and practice. I remember the story of a person with double nationality who got both passports stolen while working abroad. One consulate took one day to make a new passport, the other two months.

It really depends on how busy your consulate is; you will have to ask them. The upside is that if you want to rely on a consulate you can ask any of your country consulates. If the nearest one is busy and there is another in an easy to reach neighbouring country you can try asking the second one.

Comment: Last part is not actually true, most consulates will only process such requests if you are registered with them (which normally entails residence for more than 3 months, there are no short-term registration *anywhere*) and living in that consulate's division. Which removes doing it while backpacking or in a long trip.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella To be honest I know nothing about the consulates of Argentina. But I know that many countries make an exception to the rule for people whose document expires while they are travelling. In theory it is an emergency procedure and sometimes they issue only temporary passports that are valid only for few days. But since online processing reduced the time needed to make a full passport the temporary passports are disappearing.